# I need to detect a break in 28 V DC voltage of the order of 100 micro seconds

Tags: arduino

I need to detect a break in 28 V DC voltage of the order of 100 micro seconds.If the circuit breaks for the above mentioned duration i should get a latched output.Can someone help me.

Comment: You need a logic circuit called a flip-flop or *latch* -  a simple RS (set - reset) latch will do. But you also need to consider When / What event will reset the detector.

Comment: ... and some way of setting the threshold voltage below which an interruption is deemed to have occurred. Do we assume that the circuit is powered from the 28 V supply? Do we guess what the latch output is feeding? (Hint, hint.) What accuracy do you require on the timing? Why have you tagged this as an 'Arduino' question?

Comment: What constitutes a break? A total fall to 0V or maybe a slight glitch in the 28V? Would it not be more appropriate to measure a break in the current in the wire? Does the 28V power the latching circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Use a voltage divider and Arduino. Have it trigger an interrupt on level change (You can use that on a digital port). Then loop for 100 microseconds loooking for the level to change back up. If not, output your signal on some other pins.

Voltage divider should bring voltage down to around 4-5V, so 1:6 or so. 68kOhm and 10kOhm should be OK. Or 1kOhm / 6.8kOhm